# Is possible to Integrate Composer Adaptive Dialogs that uses LUIS as a recognizer in Bot Framework (C#)?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is possible to integrate Composer Adaptive Dialogs that use LUIS as a recognizer in Bot Framework (C#)?
Does exist any documentation to help to achieve this?

I can't find any documentation or sample that uses Composer dialog with LUIS.

This sample is the closest but does not use LUIS.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/adaptive-dialog/09.integrating-composer-dialogs

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

We have several general ways to do it, but it's ultimately up to you as the Bot developer to decide how to structure it.

A general overview to design a Knowledge bot is provided in the docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-knowledge-base?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

And here is also sample I hope helpful:
Dialog management with QnA, Luis, and Scorables : https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/10/dialog-management-qna-luis-scorables/